# Sequence of minimal surfaces with bounded second fundamental form and area

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, limits-and-convergence, minimal-surfaces

Let $M^3$ be a closed orientable smooth manifold, let $g_n$ be a sequence of Riemannian metrics on $M$ converging to $g$ and let $\Sigma_n$ be a sequence of closed orientable $g_n$-minimal surfaces embedded in $M$ such that (a): every surface in the sequence has genus $\gamma$, (b): the norm of the second fundamental form of $\Sigma_n$ is uniformly bounded above and (c): the area of $\Sigma_n$ is uniformly bounded above. **Does it follow that** the sequence smoothly converges (after passing to a subsequence) to a closed orientable embedded $g$-minimal surface of genus $\gamma$? I strongly suspect that this has an afirmative answer. Do you have references?

Comment: Try something like this: the sequence converges weakly (as varifolds, say) because of the area bounds. The curvature bounds allow you to locally write every $\Sigma_n$ as a graph with bounded (second) derivatives. This is a local result, but the size of the ball does not depend on $n$. From this you conclude smooth convergence and the regularity of the limit. That's at least the big picture.

Comment: Is the genus preserved?

Comment: I think so - for large $n$, the $\Sigma_n$ would be a graph over the limit. I should say that I glossed over a few details, in particular relating to the orientability of the limit; perhaps this might be an issue in the limit. (If say the convergence were with multiplicity two.)

Comment: If you assume the $\Sigma_n$ are connected, then the embeddedness of $\Sigma_n$, the orientablility assumptions and the regularity of the convergence that Leo Moos describes ensures that the convergence is with multiplicity one.  The argument is essentially topological and has to do with the nature of the convergence ensuring the nearest point projection to the limit surface is a covering map.  The embeddedness and orientability assumptions ensure this covering map is injective on the fundamental group (it is illustrative to see why).

Comment: Every covering map is injective in the level of fundamental groups.

Comment: Of course, not sure what I was thinking.  I meant to say that every closed loop in the limit lifts to a closed loop (if not the lift would either be non-compact or self-intersect neither of which are allowed).

Comment: I just realized I misread/misinterpred the question and glossed over the question of whether the limit was orientable.  It is possible for the limit to be non-orientable without some topological hypotheses on the ambient manifold.  For instance, on $\mathbb{RP}^3$ it should be possible to construct a metric so that there is a minimal $\mathbb{RP}^2$ that is the smooth limit (with multiplicity two) of embedded minimal two-spheres.